# Rspec: Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is bizarre because I am relatively certain that minitest is an independent testing framework from `rspec`.

In any case, what is happening is that when I run.

`rspec` at my rails root directory, I get this error:

```
Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources
```

However in my `Gemfile` I have the following:

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 4.7.5'
```

I have tried running `bundle update` and `bundle install` to no avail. Also I feel weird even adding the gem file as I only added it *after* I got the error but had no intention of using the gem to begin with.

For reference here is my `spec_helper.rb` file.

```
require 'rubygems'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to know w/o more information, it's likely something else is bringing it in if you aren't...  Do this:

1. Revert to a clean state in your repository
2. Remove minutest from `Gemfile`
3. Run `bundle` (not `update`)
4. Look in your `Gemfile.lock` and see what is depending upon `minitest`

Post the information here if the answer doesn't become clear.

You may also want re-run `rails generate rspec:install`, that `spec_helper.rb` you posted looks pretty thin.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just needed to run `bundle exec rspec` to run my tests.